# Call to a member function item() on null MX/Modules.php Line Number: 8 ckeditor and kcfinder

Tags: php, ckeditor, hmvc, kcfinder

I have trouble about ckeditor and kcfinder in codeigniter, i used HMVC from 
wiredesignz
codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc, when i want to browse images error like this

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function item() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\mypro\abbas_eterna\application\third_party\MX\Modules.php on line 8
```

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function item() on null

Filename: MX/Modules.php

Line Number: 8

Backtrace:

When i do not use HMVC to access ckeditor and browse image from kcfinder is good, and when use HMVC is trouble. I already search reference in this stackoverflow and google but not same trouble with me. i already declare in application/config.php

```
    $config['modules_locations'] = array(
    APPPATH.'modules/' => '../modules/',
);
```

and configurasi file index in root folder

```
$system_path = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'system';
$application_folder = dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'application';
```

and i use session that i setting in folder asset/kcfinder/conf/config.php

```
ob_start();
include('./../../index.php');
ob_end_clean();
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->driver('session');
if(@$_SESSION['upload_image_file_manager'] == TRUE){
    $codeigniterAuth = false;
} else {
    $codeigniterAuth = true;
}
```

Comment: Show the contents of `MX/Modules.php`, or at least the first 10 lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php (defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

(defined('EXT')) OR define('EXT', '.php');

global $CFG;

/* get module locations from config settings or use the default module location and offset */
is_array(Modules::$locations = $CFG->item('modules_locations')) OR Modules::$locations = array(
    APPPATH.'modules/' => '../modules/',
);

/* PHP5 spl_autoload */
spl_autoload_register('Modules::autoload');
```

Comment: Solved.
i change row 
is_array(Modules::$locations = $CFG->item('modules_locations')) OR Modules::$locations = array(
    APPPATH.'modules/' => '../modules/',
);

be like this
Modules::$locations = array(
 APPPATH.'modules/' => '../modules/',
);

Answer (score 0):

That error appeared cause there is the global var, at the beginning, this file
You can do this

```
Modules::$locations = array(
    APPPATH.'modules/' => '../modules/',
);
```

instead

```
is_array(Modules::$locations = $CFG->item('modules_locations')) OR 
Modules::$locations = array(
    APPPATH.'modules/' => '../modules/',
);
```